# How to access variable inside a function() to another php file

Tags: php

I included the login_auth.php file to the form_login.php and now, I want to access two variable inside the function adminAutentication to the form_login.php I tried it but did not works.

login_auth.php

```
$uname_err= '';
$psswd_err = '';

function adminAuthentication() {
   $psswd_err = "The password you entered was not valid!";
   $uname_err = "No account found with that username!";
}
```

form_login.php

```
<?php include 'login_auth.php'; ?>

<form method="post">
   <div class="form-group">
       <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $uname_err ?></span> // problem here cannot access the variable
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $psswd_err; ?></span> // problem here cannot access the variable
   </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Did the include work? Error message(s) PLEASE SHOW is you have any?? You could try changing the `incude` to a `require` so that the page crashes if the `login_auth.php` cannot be found

Comment: Do you call `adminAuthentication`? Also describe `cannot access the variable`, is it empty, undefined, or something else?

Comment: If you want the error message loaded into the variables declared above the function, you are going to have to fix the SCOPE issue first. Pass the variables as parameters to the function

Comment: ___but did not works.___ Please be more specific.

Comment: We would normally expect to see some sort of testing of entered variables BEFORE creating error messages, Not just a function to load all errors for no apparent reason

Answer (score 0):

inside the adminAuthentication() function you have to declare the global variables:

```
function adminAuthentication() {
   global $psswd_err, $uname_err ;
   $psswd_err = "The password you entered was not valid!";
   $uname_err = "No account found with that username!";
}
```